# How to get the MFC view in millimeters (mm)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have to draw a line so that — for example — if the input width value of line is 20 mm then the width of the line drawn should be in 20 mm. I read in MFC documentation that the input width value that we provide is considered as units by the MFC and the drawn object values are in pixels. Can anyone tell me how to set and get the width scaling in mm .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`SetMapMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setmapmode).

> The `SetMapMode` function sets the mapping mode of the specified device context. The mapping mode defines the unit of measure used to transform page-space units into device-space units, and also defines the orientation of the device's x and y axes.

Look at `MM_LOMETRIC` or `MM_HIMETRIC`:

> Each logical unit is mapped to **0.01 millimeter**. Positive x is to the right; positive y is up.

Towards the bottom of the article it states:

> The `MM_HIENGLISH`, `MM_HIMETRIC`, `MM_LOENGLISH`, `MM_LOMETRIC`, and `MM_TWIPS` modes are useful for applications drawing in physically meaningful units (such as inches or **millimeters**).

Comment: Hi Andrew I studied the mapping modes and started using MM_HIMETRIC. Thankyou good day

Comment: @VikranthN Please consider up-voting and accepting my answer if it has been useful for you.